# Trying to make a error checker to check if there is a number in the string, but it never works

Tags: python

```
def ercheck (var):
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
    error = False
    for num in nums:
        if str(num) not in (var):
            error = True
    for char in str(var):
        if char not in (var):
            error = True
    if error == True:
        print("Invalid argument(s), Try again.")
        quit()
```

It always gives me the error message, that I coded in. After some testing, it seems like the `for num in nums: if str(num) not in (var): error = True` is the problem.

Comment: What is an example of `var`?

Comment: BTW: You can eliminate the list `nums` and the str conversion with `for c in '0123456789': ...`

Comment: @dawg user-inputted string that is supposed to have only numbers, but if it has any un-number character the error is supposed to go off. Examples: (correct) 500. (wrong) 11!1.

Comment: @AmmarAldabbagh ah so you want to check if the var string is a number and doesn't have non numeric values in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if the input string is a number, you can use .isnumeric().

```
def ercheck (var):
    if not str(var).isnumeric():
        print("Invalid argument(s), Try again.")

ercheck("500")
# 
ercheck("11!1")
# Invalid argument(s), Try again.
```

---

You can use 2 things: string.isnumeric() checks if a string or a character is numeric. any() checks if any value in a iterable is true.

```
def ercheck (var):
    if any((x.isnumeric() for x in var)): print("Invalid argument(s), Try again.")
    
ercheck("abcde")
#
ercheck("ab4cde")
#Invalid argument(s), Try again.
```

Comment: the thing is I'm still learning python, and the learning program assumes I can make the check with things I learned from the program itself...

Comment: @AmmarAldabbagh, all those things are nativ python functions, so no import required. But I understand, you need a simpler way correct? I adjust my answer in a min and provide a second solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a string that is only digits, you can do:

```
def err(var):
   try:
      int(var)
   except ValueError:
      print("Invalid argument {}, Try again.".format(var))
```

You can also do:

```
def err(var):
   return bool(set(var)-set('0123456789')
```

Comment: the thing is I'm still learning python, and the learning program assumes I can make the check with things I learned from the program itself...

Comment: The set substraction is a nice idea.